# HM-10 iBeacon: Why is the AT+MEAS command not answered?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, ibeacon, hm-10

I am trying to query an HM-10 iBeacon measured power using `AT+MEAS?` with no success. The module does not respond at all.

I have checked my HM-10 software version using `AT+VERS?` and it answers **HMSoft V540**. The datasheet says that the `AT+MEAS` command was added in **V519** version, so this should be not the problem (except they removed it, but the datasheet does not say anything about the removal of the `AT+MEAS` command).

I am referring to this [datasheet](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.15/doc/tutorials/programming/bluetooth/bluetooth40_en.pdf).

Also, I have tried to run the `AT+MEAS?` command before and after I enable iBeacon mode using `AT+IBEA1`, both with no success.

I run the commands in the Arduino Serial Monitor (no line ending, 9600 baud). The rest of the commands seem to work just fine, only `AT+MEAS` does not work, both for query (`AT+MEAS?`) and setting a value (ex. `AT+MEAS0xFFE9`).

Does anyone know how to query and set HM-10 iBeacon measured power, or to make the `AT+MEAS` command work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

So apparently I referred to a "not so right" datasheet for my HM-10 module. After searching a little bit, I found this [datasheet](https://www.tinyosshop.com/datasheet/Tinysine%20Serial%20Bluetooth4%20user%20manual.pdf).

It turns out that to query and set my HM-10 iBeacon measured power, the commands are `AT+MEA??` and `AT+MEA[param]` respectively.